# Error de tipo (Type Error) al iterar sobre columnas de una matriz (listas anidadas) e imprimirlas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Dada esta lista de listas:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

Quiero crear una función qué imprima el siguiente dibujo:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

para eso usé un bucle for in dentro de otro for in:

```
def printPic(grid):
    for n in grid:
        for i in grid:
            print(grid[i][n])
```

Y el resultado no es el esperado:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás mezclando dos formas diferentes de iterar sobre una lista, indexado e iteraración directamente con un `for in`.

Cuando se usa `for elemento in lista:` la variable `elemento` hace referencia a cada item de la lista directamente, no un índice. El error se debe por tanto  a que `n` e `i` son ambas una lista (una fila (lista anidada) de la lista `grid`), no un entero como se espera de un índice. Esto causa que, en la primera iteración por ejemplo, estés haciendo realmente:

```
grid[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']][['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

en vez de:

```
grid[0][0]
```

Si quieres usar un `for in`, que es por otra parte lo recomendado, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
def print_pic(grid):
    for row in zip(*grid):
        print("".join(row))
```

o si lo prefieres usando una sola llamada a `print`:

```
def print_pic(grid):
    print("\n".join("".join(row) for row in zip(*grid)))
```

- `*grid` "desempaqueta" las sublistas (filas) de la lista, de forma que es algo similar a:

  ```
  zip(lista[0], lista[1], ..., lista[n])
  ```
- `zip` permite iterar de forma simultanea sobre las filas, en la primera iteración retorna el primer elemento de cada fila (primera columna), en la segunda iteración retorna el segundo elemento de cada fila  (segunda columna), etc.
- `str.join` simplemente toma todos los elementos de la columna (caracteres) y los une en una sola cadena.

Si quieres usar indexado, que es posiblemente tu idea original, puedes hacer por ejemplo:

```
def print_pic(grid):
    for i in range(len(grid[0])):
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[j][i], end="")
        print()
```

Igual que antes puedes hacer uso de `str.join`:

```
def print_pic2(grid):
    for i in range(len(grid[0])):
        print("".join(grid[j][i] for j in range(len(grid))))
```

O más críptica todavía:

```
def print_pic2(grid):
    print("\n".join("".join(grid[j][i] for j in range(len(grid)))
                                           for i in range(len(grid[0]))))
```

---

> ```
> >>> print_pic(grid)
> ..OO.OO..
> .OOOOOOO.
> .OOOOOOO.
> ..OOOOO..
> ...OOO...
> ....O....
> ```